# Pokemon Go: Can't log in?

Tags: pokemon-go

Are everyone unable to log in right now? 2016 July 16. Where I live none can log in to the servers at the moment, and it all happened after the sudden release of the game in my country.

As I understand the game was recently released in 26 countries, so I guess they have problems and had the servers go offline in order to fix the issues.

Comment: They added Pokemon Go to Poland and maybe other countries. We cant log in in Poland too - servers are humbled or smth.

Comment: Yup it released in 26 new countries so can be the reason, hope it get fixed soon.

Comment: It is down in the US, too.

Comment: Looks like it's just PoddleCorp not new countries :/

Answer (score 6):

The servers are currently down, thanks to Niantic's ingenious idea to release to 26 new countries on a Saturday.

Be patient.

Comment: Guess ur wrong.

Comment: PoddleCorp said that they took down Pokemon Go servers, looks like it's not becouse of new countries.

Comment: @HardnerPL them claiming responsibility doesn't necessarily mean that they are responsible

Comment: @HardnerPL I'm saying they're down because they didn't praise helix enough, so you're wrong.

Comment: @Mouer but IMHO It makes more sense than new countries. Why? I guess most people from this 26 countries already played Pokemon Go before it was added to their countries, also i don't think Niantic would make so bad mistake :)

Comment: @HardnerPL The servers have been having issues since day 1. Today is Saturday, and a load of new countries have been added, causing a spike in traffic. PoodleCorp, on the other hand, are notorious for lying about server outages being DDoSes. And bigger companies than Niantic have been stingy with their servers; often deliberately.