# Forgot password on Pokemon go how do I get it back

Tags: pokemon-go

I had 60+ Pokemon and a few rare, Pokemon go wasn't loading so I turned my phone off. When I tried to go back on Pokemon go I went to the starting screen. When I I tried to login I realized I forget my password so when I clicked forgot password nothing happend so please help me

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275274/pokemon-go-cant-log-in maybe that's why.

Answer (score 1):

The "forgot password" feature does NOT work on MOBILE DEVICES. It worked for me only on my laptop. You have to go through the whole process on the laptop. Also, this didn't work for me when the app wasn't loading for a friend. I had to go back later and do it when the app was working.

Answer (score -1):

The "forgot password" feature simply **does not work**. Although it claims that it will send you an e-mail to allow you to recover your password, it **doesn't actually do anything**, unfortunately.

At this moment, the only options you have are a) make a new account and **lose everything** or b) **wait indefinitely** until they fix the password recovery feature.